# Query inside unique document inside collection in Firestore

Tags: ios, swift, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to query for an id inside an array of a document, but I just found a way that I query inside the whole collection, and I think this is not the most optimized way to do this.

*This is what I'm thinking about:*

```
theColletionReference.document("theDocumentId").whereField("fieldName", arrayContains: ["theIdImLookingFor"]).getDocument{
 //the code remaining
}
```

I know that the code above is wrong, but that is the idea I'm trying to implement!

*This is my database:*
[image]

Comment: It's not clear where you are stuck implementing your idea.  I suggest actually trying your idea to use arrayContains, then post the code that doesn't work the way you expect.

Comment: @DougStevenson The code works well, but I want to know if there is a way to query within a single document, because, the way I found,  queries within the entire collection of documents, and this is not necessary, because I have the document ID where I should consult.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do anything at all with a single document, simply get() it and examine the contents of the document sbapshot to see if it contains what you want. There is no need for a full query just to see if a document contains some value.

Comment: How do I do it, I mean, I know how to get the single document, but how do I query on it? I tried using where, but doesn't work!

Comment: You can't query on a single document.  You can just get it.  Look at the DocumentSnapshot in memory if you want to know what's inside.  Use normal swift array operations on its fields if you want.

Comment: So, what you mean is, I get the whole array, and query it on the user-side?

Comment: Yes, you can do that. Buy it won't be called a "query". It is just checking an array for the existence of a string.

Comment: I got it! But, is there another way to do it? Because, for example, an array with 3.000 ids inside, it would be very "painful" to the user, or am I wrong?? I  just started learning Firestore, so I still have some difficulty with it!

Comment: There is no other way to do it, and I think you'll find that even iterating an array of 3000 items will be instantaneous.  I think you're trying too hard to optimize this.

Comment: I think I got it !!! Can I ask one more thing? For example, using the same arrays with ids, is there a way to count the number of elements within it, without getting all the ids? Because in what I'm doing here, it is not necessary to get the ids, just the amount of elements inside it!

Comment: If you have a new question, please post that separately.